# How to show unordered list within window.alert()?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm a newbie to the web development scene.  I was just wondering if it was possible to show an unordered list within a javascript pop up box somehow (with window.alert()).  I figure this has a really straightforward solution, but putting html code for a list within the parentheses does not seem to work.  Thank you for any help in advance.

Putting html code for a list within parentheses does not seem to work.

I expect a pop up box with an unordered list when a checkbox is clicked, but checking the box does not seem to work when html code for an unordered list is within the window.alert().

Comment: One option is showing a `<div>` with position fixed to show the `<ul>`

Comment: Are you able to use a "modal window" instead?

Comment: [`alert()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert) is only for displaying a plain text string; it will not render HTML. I suggest searching for tutorials on creating popups or dialogs; there are plenty of resources out there.

Comment: `window.alert()` will not work to render HTML, like @Adriano suggested, a modal may be what you are looking for. Modal example: https://jquerymodal.com/

Comment: A modal does seem like a much better idea.  I wil be able to use an unordered list with a modal, correct?

Comment: Correct, 100%! :)

Answer (score 2):

Since [`alert`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert) works with text and you have bullet characters like `•` and `○`, you can create a list (see snippet).

```js
function createUnorderedList(list, bulletChar) {
  var result = "";
  for (var i = 0; i<list.length; ++i) {
    result += bulletChar + " " + list[i] + "\n";
  }
  return result;
}

function createOrderedList(list) {
  var result = "";
  for (var i = 0; i<list.length; ++i) {
    result += (i+1) + ". " + list[i] + "\n";
  }
  return result;
}

function a() {
  var bulletChar = "○";
  var list = ["hi", "hello", "bye"]
  
  var text = "You can create an unordered list manually, but it's better if you use modal like others suggested."
  alert(text + "\n" + createUnorderedList(list, bulletChar));
}

function b() {
  var list = ["hi", "hello", "bye"]
  
  var text = "You can also create an ordered list manually, but it's better if you use modal like others suggested."
  alert(text + "\n" + createOrderedList(list));
}

function c() {
  var bulletChar = "•";
  var list = ["You", "checked", "the", "box"]
  alert(createUnorderedList(list, bulletChar));
}
```

```html
<button onclick="a()">Unordered list</button><br />
<button onclick="b()">Ordered list</button><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" onclick="c()">Triggered with a checkbox</label>
```

That said, as others suggested, it's probably better to learn how to create modals (an example tutorial can be found [here](https://hackernoon.com/the-ultimate-guide-for-creating-a-simple-modal-component-in-vanilla-javascript-react-angular-8733e2859b42)). You can use any HTML with them so it solves more than just the unordered list problem you're facing.

Answer (score 0):

Use modal.alert box is a system object no html or css will work.You can create html alert and show or hide using javascript show() and hide event on click.

Answer (score 0):

key ponit is the css attr "display: none/block"

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>fbfatboy</title>
    <style>
        .my-alert{
            position: fixed;
            display: none;
            left: 50%;
            top: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            background-color: lightblue;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<button class='do-alert'>alert</button>
<button class='do-hide'>hide-alert</button>
<div class="my-alert">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">3</a></li>
        <li><a href="">4</a></li>
        <li><a href="">5</a></li>
        <li><a href="">6</a></li>
        <li><a href="">7</a></li>
        <li><a href="">8</a></li>
        <li><a href="">9</a></li>
        <li><a href="">10</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script>
  window.onload = function(){
    document.querySelector('.do-alert').onclick = function(){
      document.querySelector('.my-alert').style.display = 'block'
    }
    document.querySelector('.do-hide').onclick = function(){
      document.querySelector('.my-alert').style.display = 'none'
    }
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```